# update all the fields in table which have empty values (MYSQL)

Tags: sql, mysql

Is there any way to update all the records in a table if there is atleast one filed which has empty value?

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to be a little more specific than that.

Comment: You mean at least 1 row has that column empty, update the whole column for all rows?

Comment: yes, if a particular record has empty value, then it should get filled in with the update that I specify. This should happen with all the rows in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not without using all the fields in the query. If this is your table:

```
col0: TEXT NULL,
col1: TEXT NULL,
col2: INT NULL
```

you can issue:

```
UPDATE YourTable SET col0='yourValue' WHERE col1 IS NULL or col2 IS NULL
```

Comment: Is there are lot of cols , is there any way to avoid mentioning all the ones?

Comment: no, there isn't, you'll need to provide them manually. But you have the option of fetching existing column names from the according schema table: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html